# What does T mean in file permissions?

Tags: raspbian, linux

I was wondering what the letter T means on the following results.

```
$ ls -l /dev/mem
crw-r----T 1 root kmem 1, 1 Jan  1  1970 /dev/mem
```

I have changed the permissions and now I don't know how restore that letter T.

Comment: check this answer http://superuser.com/questions/87037/what-is-the-meaning-of-t-in-the-execution-permissions-of-a-directory

Answer (score 1):

Finally i figure out thanks to @SteveRobillard link.

To restore to original priviliges:

```
sudo chmod 640 /dev/mem
sudo chmod +t /dev/mem
```

Answer (score 0):

Smething with t permission is something that can only be moved or deleted by that object's owner, the directory owner, or the super-user.